# Meaning of star symbol by each question?

Tags: discussion, support, user-interface, bookmarks

To the left of each question there is an upvote arrow, a vote count, a downvote arrow, and a little star symbol. What is the star symbol?

Comment: As with most things, numbers, dates on SE: Just hover with your cursor over the symbol and you will be shown a tooltip. In this case, the tooltip says: *This is a favorite question (click again to undo)*

Comment: @MartinSleziak: Unfortunately, one can't hover using an iPad

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The $\Large \star$ button, when clicked on, becomes $\color{orange}{\Large \star}$, signaling that the question was added to the user's favorite question's list. You can access this list in your profile.

The number of users who added the question to its favorite's is shown below the star.

Related: [How do favorite questions work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53585/how-do-favorite-questions-work)

Comment: Oh, man, that is great!  I don't know how many times I've tried to search for a question I've seen and couldn't find it. This is extremely helpful, thanks!

Comment: @MPW Yes. Plus deleted questions will not be deleted from your favorite question's list, (unless you 'unfavourite' them).

Comment: I love your user picture/avatar. I just realized the KFC spoof--hilarious!

Comment: To see deleted questions on the list of favorites, @MPW would need 10K rep.

Comment: @Thisismuchhealthier. I forgot that. Thanks.